# Protractor : mocking EventSource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Is there remotely any way to mock any SSE (Server Sent Event) from a Protractor test ?

That means mocking `EventSource`

Angular controller :

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', function() {

  var monitoringEvents = new window.EventSource('/streams/jobserveur');

  monitoringEvents.addEventListener('monitoring-event', function(e) {
    var json = JSON.parse(e.data);    
    ...
  });
});
```

Thank you for any insight

Comment: Can you show some code where that mocking would be needed? (Or some code you tried and didn't work?)

Comment: I added the controller code where the EventSource is referenced.
I have litteraly no idea on how I could mock this thing. Maybe I could encapsulate the `EventSource` into an Angular module and use the `AddMockModule` in the test ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to mock `EventSource` by the solution I mentionned (angular module/protractor addMockModule).

1. Externalize `EventSource` calls into a dedicated angular module

   ```
   angular.module('app.sse', [])
   .value('$sse', {
     sources : [],
     addEventSource : function(name, url) {
       this.sources[name] = new window.EventSource(url);
     },
     addEventListener : function(name, eventName, callback) {
       this.sources[name].addEventListener(eventName, callback);
     }
   });
   ```
2. Referencing the module in the app

   ```
   angular.module('app', ['app.sse', ...])
   ```
3. Use the `$sse` module in the app

   ```
   angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', ['$sse' , function($sse) {
     $sse.addEventSource('jobserveur', '/streams/jobserveur');

     $sse.addEventListener('jobserveur', 'monitoring-event', function(e) {
       var js = JSON.parse(e.data);
     }
   }]);
   ```

   From here, make sure your app still work before moving onto the testing
4. Mock the `app.sse` module in your test

   ```
   describe('SSE Fixture', function() {
     beforeEach(function() {
       browser.addMockModule('app.sse', function() {
         angular.module('app.sse', []).value('$sse', {
           addEventSource: function(name, url) {

           },
           addEventListener: function(name, event, callback) {

           }
         });
     });
   }
   ```

   And you're done ! Obviously, the two methods are not implemented here nor is the `app.sse` module in anyway robust but you get the picture.

Hope it helps anyone

Cheers